# How to build Keycloak source code on Windows System

Tags: java, keycloak

I want to build Keycloak from source code on my computer to perform some coding.
I followed the steps described in the Readme file on the git repository one by one.

```
 - Java version : 17.0.2
 - Maven version : 3.9.1
 - Git is already installed
```

However, when I proceed to run the command "mvn clean install" after cloning the project, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] ConfigurationTest.testDatabaseDefaults:259 
expected:jdbc:h2:file:C:[\Users\inesb\data\]h2/keycloakdb;;AUTO_... but 
was:jdbc:h2:file:C:[/Users/inesb/data/]h2/keycloakdb;;AUTO_... [ERROR] 
ConfigurationTest.testDatabaseProperties:337 expected:jdbc:h2:file: 
[C:\Users\inesb\data\h2/keycloakdb;;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE];NON_KEYWORDS=VALUE 
but was:jdbc:h2:file:[test- 
dir/data/h2/keycloakdb;;test=test;test1=test1];NON_KEYWORDS=VALUE
```

I also tried the command `"mvn clean install -Pdistribution -DskipTests"`.

But, I still get a build failure due the same error.

I believe this issue may be related to path inconsistencies in the test configuration. However, I couldn't find a solution to the problem.

I tried to modify the `ConfigurationTest` Class by implementing the Path class to create a Path object to represent the file path.

However, it did not solve the issue.

Comment: The issue seems to be with your configuration. It's expecting the h2 database path but it's not finding it.

Comment: I tried to resolve the issue by adding the path manually to the "pom.xml" file. However, it's not solved. Thus, I decided to build module by module. Now, I have the following error in the operator folder: "Command execution failed.: Cannot run program "C:\Users\inesb\keycloak\operator\patch-sources.sh" (in directory "C:\Users\inesb\keycloak\operator"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application -> [Help 1]" .  Knowing Keycloak can be installed on Windows, I don't know why I have this architecture mismatch.

Comment: It's using the sh script. So will be built on a Linux machine or you have to install Cygwin or Linux subsystem. But it's not sure shell script uses which commands. So I would suggest to build on Linux.

Comment: Is it possible to use Docker as another alternative ?